# CopyFile from one directory to another (C++)

Tags: c++, windows, c++11, file-rename, file-copying

i'm working on Windows and i'm trying to simply move a file from one directory to another. 
I use the method "CopyFile" but i have an issue whith the name of the file copied; i'm trying this:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

std::string source_path = "C:/ProgramData/RTD02/versions/versions.txt";
std::string destination_path = "C:/ProgramData/RTD02/principale.txt";
CopyFile(source_path.c_str(), destination_path.c_str(), 0);
```

In fact the content of the file "versions.txt" is well copied into the file "principale.txt". But what i want is also to change the name of file "principale.txt" to "versions.txt", i tried this one but it didn't work :

```
 rename(destination_path.c_str(), source_path.c_str());
```

Thanks,

Comment: If your compiler supports C++17 - you could make use of this - https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/rename

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't support, the method rename() that i use is from <stdio.h>

Comment: @JaziriRami: C++ has overloads; the `std::rename` from `<cstdio.h>` can co-exist with the one from `<filesystem>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is that your destination string needs to be, well the destination.

```
std::string destination_path = "C:/ProgramData/RTD02/versions.txt";
```

If you meant to replace an existing file you then follow up a successful copy with [`DeleteFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-deletefilea) the `principale.txt`

Comment: Thanks @acraig5075 ! it was because of the paths i use in the rename() method; that's the correction:                                                 
rename("C:/ProgramData/RTD02/principale.txt","C:/ProgramData/RTD02/versions.txt");

Answer (score 0):

The Windows function to move a file is called just that, [`MoveFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-movefile). Works just like `CopyFile`.

Comment: yes you are right, they are functions from <WinBase.h>